# Understanding 物事をかけらもうたがわないたちなのだ

Tags: translation, words, reading-comprehension, sentence

I am nearing the end of the first chapter of Kaori Ekuni's *Twinkle Twinkle*. However, I failed to parse the following sentence in bold (the rest of the passage is provided below for context):

> 気にいった？　もちろん、とこたえた瞬間に、私はとんでもないことを思い出した。クリスマスだというのに、私は睦月に何も買っていないのだ。プレゼントのことなんて、考えてもみなかった。
>
> 「さて、何食べにいく？」
>
> 「あのね、睦月」
>
> 私、あなたに天体望遠鏡を買ったんだけど、年末でしょ、配達に日数がいるみたいで。——あんまりすらすらと嘘がでてくるので、私は自分でおどろいてしまう。
>
> 「すごい！」
>
> 睦月は目をかがやかせた。**私の夫は、物事をかけらもうたがわないたちなのだ。**
>
> （江國香織『きらきらひかる』）

My understanding so far is as follows: the narrator feels guilty for always receiving presents from her husband. So she lies to him about gifting him a telescope at the end of the year.

From the response of her husband, and my understanding of the words `物事` (things) and `疑う` (to doubt), the sentence in bold seems to be a comment on her husband's simple-mindedness or lack of suspicion. I cannot however understand how `かけら` and `たち` contribute to the sentence (assuming I parsed it correctly) – am I missing something important here? How should I interpret this sentence properly?

Comment: Related? (Regarding たち) https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/58598/9831

Comment: @Chocolate thank you! That seems to be it. I just couldn't bend my mind into thinking anything other than the plural indicator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 私の夫は、物事をかけらもうたがわないたちなのだ。

The たち (質) means "one's nature" "disposition".

かけら (欠片) originally means "fragment" "piece", and かけらも～～ない means "not ... even a bit" "not ... at all".

So you're right that the line is a comment on her husband's lack of suspicion. It means "My husband is a kind of person who doesn't doubt things even a little."

Comment: Thank you! Just a follow-up question: in terms of nuance, how would you differentiate between 普通形＋たちだ and ます形＋がちだ?

Comment: And is ちっとも a more colloquial saying than かけらも?

Comment: We use 「～するたちだ」 to talk about one's inherent characteristics, nature, while 「～しがちだ」 just means one tends to do something. I think かけらも～ない is a bit literary(文学的) and emphatic way of saying すこしも～ない.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you so much!